# Closed on Topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

For $S=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots,\frac1n\}$

Prove that $S$ is closed on $\mathbb R$

I thought as,

$S=\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$ 
for any $x$ we can find $x=(a,b) \subset S$ such as 
$a=n+1$ and $b=1$.

So doesn't it make $S$ open?

Comment: A singleton set is closed in $\mathbb R$. What about a finite union of closed sets?

Comment: However, we can say union of finitely many closed sets is closed. In here, I don't know how to show it is closed

Comment: what is your definition of closed?

Comment: If we can say its compliment is open, then we can say it's closed. That's why in here I was trying to show if it's open or not. If it didn't seem open to me, I would try to show its compliment is open.

Comment: A set can be both open and closed at the same time.

Comment: Let $U = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and $x\in U$. Can you find an open interval $I$ with $I\subseteq U$?

Comment: Yes sure, like R

Comment: @EmreYılmaz nope, $\mathbb R$ contains $0$ which is not in $U$. You might want draw a picture.

Comment: A prior comment asks for your def'n of closed. Definitions are tools to be used. Always start with the def'ns. See  whether the set satisfies each condition of the def'n.